# How do I fix a weird security error on an old local drive?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, security, windows-explorer

**Context:**

I used a hard disk as my Windows installation disk until I finally upgraded to a solid state drive. I now use my old local drive as drive G: for extra storage. I did not format it because it contained valuable data, and I don't have the extra storage (or money) to remove the data, format the disk, and return the data. I will probably do this later if there is no easier solution.

**Problem:**

Trying to create or paste a file in the root directory of the old local drive results in this error:

```
Error 0x80070522: A required privilege is not held by the client.
```

However, I can create or paste a file in any existing folders on the old local drive just fine. After that, I can cut/paste from elsewhere on the drive to the root directory! So there's my workaround. But why am I not allowed to create or paste anything directly in that root directory?

**More info:**

Windows 7 Home Premium Service Pack 1 64-bit

The security settings for the drive are exactly the same as my two others non-local drives (with minor useless differences with the Users group; I only ever deal with Administrators because this is a one-user computer).

Using chkdsk found no problems. Likewise, Hard Disk Sentinel sees nothing wrong with any of my drives.

Comment: If you installed Windows on the SSD, then the users belonging to that installation, do not have access to the data stored contained within a user profile on the HDD.  If you want to access that data you have to take ownership of it as an Administrator.

Comment: I already have access to all the data on my old local drive. I'm pretty sure I claimed ownership of them after I made the switch. (This was one or two years ago; I'm only now getting around to asking about this weird issue.)

Comment: So the root directory of a system partition is a protected directory under Windows,  Even if that system partition is from another installation.  The error you recieved is a permission issue, which indicates, you have not taken ownership of the root directory of that drive.

Comment: Just tried it. Nothing changed.